# Power from piezo material

Tags: energy, ceramics

Suppose there is a given piezoelectric material and under a given force it produces voltage $V$. If an external electric circuit is attached with load $R$, the current will be $I= V/R$. Also power generated will be $V^2/R$. By choosing $R$ very low, high energy can be obtained. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong for at least two reasons.

First, if you apply a *constant* force to the piezoelectric material, you will produce a voltage across it but *no* current will flow. You can only generate a current by doing *mechanical work* on the material. That means you only get a current while you are *changing* the force, and therefore changing the amount that the material bends or stretches.

Second, you are ignoring the internal electrical impedance of the material. If the impedance was a constant resistance, it is fairly easy to show that the maximum power in the load occurs when the load $R$ is the same as the internal resistance. See the [Maximum Power Transfer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem). If $R$ is smaller than this, most of the power is "wasted" within the piezo material instead of being transferred to the load. If $R$ is bigger, the higher impedance of the complete circuit reduces the power that is generated, in a similar way to your attempt at analysing what happens using Ohm's law.

The same idea applies to a piezoelectric material, but the internal impedance is more like a capacitance than a resistance, so you need to analyze the behaviour of the circuit for an alternating current, and the amount of power transferred depends on the *frequency* of the force applied to the material, as well as on the internal and load impedances. Basically, you get more power by moving the piezo material faster.